# Why the image view android:layout_below is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

In this page, the `@+id/photo_area` is dynamic generate as I would like the width align to height , so I have write the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/share_bg" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo_area"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/share_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/photo_area"
                android:layout_above="@+id/share_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/share_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/share_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/share_submit"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_textarea"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:lines="5"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/default_msg" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/share_submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/photo_taken_btn_submit" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the program , I set the params on the photo

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.share_pic_form);

            ctx = this;

            prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
            editor = prefs.edit();

            tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);

            permission = new ArrayList<String>();
            permission.add("email");

            Utility.setHeader(this,R.string.selfie_header,false);

            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session == null) {
                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, callback, savedInstanceState);
                }
                if (session == null) {
                    session = new Session(this);
                }
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(permission).setCallback(callback));
                }
            }

            photoArea = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_area);
            int size = (int)(Utility.getScreenWidth(this)); 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
            imgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
             //imgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.share_title);
            photoArea.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            photoArea.setLayoutParams(imgParams);
            photoArea.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
            photoArea.getBackground().setAlpha(204); // = 0.8 alpha

            shareTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share_title);
            shareContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.share_content);

            if (getIntent() != null) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                fileUri = (String) intent.getStringExtra("photo");
                catId = (String) intent.getStringExtra("catId");
            } else if (savedInstanceState != null){
                mBitmap = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap") == null ? null : (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap");
                catId = (String) savedInstanceState.getString("catId");
            }

            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
            File imgSelected = new File(fileUri);

            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(imgSelected);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.get_photo_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

            mBitmap = Utility.decodeBitmap(inputStream, 1280, 960);

            if (mBitmap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.get_photo_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                photoArea.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);                  
                sharePhotoBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.share_submit);
                sharePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("form_button","Category_form","SubmitnShare_" + Utility.getLocale(ctx),null).build());
                        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO);
                    }
                });
            }

        }


The problem is , in the xml /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.share_pic_form);

        ctx = this;

        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
        editor = prefs.edit();

        tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);

        permission = new ArrayList<String>();
        permission.add("email");

        Utility.setHeader(this,R.string.selfie_header,false);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, callback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(permission).setCallback(callback));
            }
        }

        photoArea = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_area);
        int size = (int)(Utility.getScreenWidth(this)); 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
        imgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
         //imgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.share_title);
        photoArea.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        photoArea.setLayoutParams(imgParams);
        photoArea.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
        photoArea.getBackground().setAlpha(204); // = 0.8 alpha

        shareTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share_title);
        shareContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.share_content);

        if (getIntent() != null) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            fileUri = (String) intent.getStringExtra("photo");
            catId = (String) intent.getStringExtra("catId");
        } else if (savedInstanceState != null){
            mBitmap = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap") == null ? null : (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap");
            catId = (String) savedInstanceState.getString("catId");
        }

        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        File imgSelected = new File(fileUri);

        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(imgSelected);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.get_photo_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        mBitmap = Utility.decodeBitmap(inputStream, 1280, 960);

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.get_photo_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            photoArea.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);                  
            sharePhotoBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.share_submit);
            sharePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("form_button","Category_form","SubmitnShare_" + Utility.getLocale(ctx),null).build());
                    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

The problem is , `the layout_below photo_area` for `share_title` is not working. It seems the photo_area is on top of it, how to fix the problem ? thanks

Comment: In your layout I see a lot of **id creations** (**@+id**), where **id references** (**@id**) should be. This can lead to errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs `layout_below`:

[Positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_below)

so, yes, the photo area in your case will be above

You, probably, would want to change to `layout_above`